# Audio 3D in Unity with ARCore

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I downloaded the ARCore example for Unity, and I used HelloAR scene. When the app recognizes a flat place, it shows me my 3D object, to which I added 3D audios, but in spite of moving, the audio is heard 2D. Is it possible to implement 3D audio in Unity with ARCore?

Comment: Oh this is a cool question actually. A little bit more information would be nice of course. I am assuming you adjusted all 3D sound setting in [Audio Source](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html)

Comment: Bumping this question because I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an audio listener on the First Person Camera.

Best,